# Puzzle: Spreading numbers evenly in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is more of a puzzle really.  Its probably been asked elsewhere before, but I couldn't find anything so I thought I'd share the question.

I'm trying to implement some kind of load balancing in an application and have reduced the problem down to what I believe should be a simple TSQL exercise (the application is predominantly in the SQL Server domain (SQL Server 2008 R2)).

Basically I have a table with two integers; a unique, sequential  Id and a non-unique Value.  The table could hold any number of records and I'd like to produce a table of data where the first n largest Values are split into separate 'groupings' and then the second set of n largest Values are split into separate 'groupings'.

I've got a first draft working below but I believe it can be improved...

```
DECLARE @GroupCount INT = 5

-- Set up the test data
DECLARE @test TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Value INT)
INSERT  @Test (Value)
VALUES  (100), (456), (121), (402), (253), (872), (765), (6529), (1029), (342), (98), (1), (0), (4), (46), (23), (456), (416), (2323), (4579)


--Order by Value descending
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) RowNum
    FROM    @Test
)
--use modulus to split into grouping
, cte2 AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RowNum % @GroupCount ORDER BY RowNum DESC) Rnk
    FROM    cte
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk ORDER BY Value DESC) AS 'Grouping'
    ,Value
    ,Id
FROM    cte2
ORDER BY [Grouping], Value ASC
```

This works and produces the following dataset:

```
Grouping,   Value,      Id
========    =====       ==
1           46          15
1           342         10
1           765         7
1           6529        8
2           23          16
2           253         5
2           456         2
2           4579        20
3           4           14
3           121         3
3           456         17
3           2323        19
4           1           12
4           100         1
4           416         18
4           1029        9
5           0           13
5           98          11
5           402         4
5           872         6
```

The dataset returned is correct in that the first n largest values are split into separate groupings and so on but the total values in each grouping are quite different in grouping 1 compared to grouping 5 (for example).

When grouped and SUMmed we can see the un-even spread:

```
Grouping,   SummedValues
========    ============
1           7682
2           5311
3           2904
4           1546
5           1372
```

In as few lines as possible how can I better balance the Values so that the total Values in each grouping is more evenly spread?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks - I wasn't sure what to call this problem.  That kind of describes it - I guess this problem is a variant at least.

Comment: I think your biggest issue is your small sample size here.  Over a sample size of 1000 items ranging in size from 0-10000, the snake method works pretty darn well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is flawed, but not terrible for given the example data. Your mileage may vary.

```
declare @groupcount int = 5;
create table t (id int identity(1, 1), value int);
insert  t values 
    (100),(456),(121),(402),(253),(872),(765),(6529),(1029),(342)
  , (98),(1),(0),(4),(46),(23),(456),(416),(2323),(4579);
;with cte as (
  select *
      , rn = row_number() over (order by value asc)
      , pct = value/sum(value+.0) over()
      , target = 1.0 / @groupcount 
  from t
)
, remaining as (
select id, value, rn
  , grp = convert(int,(sum(value) over (order by rn)/sum(value+.0) over())*@groupCount)+1
from cte
)
select
    grp = row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc)
  , sumValue = sum(value)
from remaining
group by grp
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UNV61100

results:

```
+-----+----------+
| grp | sumValue |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |     6529 |
|   2 |     4579 |
|   3 |     3483 |
|   4 |     2323 |
|   5 |     1901 |
+-----+----------+
```

---

Sql Server 2008 compatable version:

```
declare @groupcount int = 5;
create table t (id int identity(1, 1), value int);
insert  t values 
    (100),(456),(121),(402),(253),(872),(765),(6529),(1029),(342)
  , (98),(1),(0),(4),(46),(23),(456),(416),(2323),(4579);
;with cte as (
  select *
      , rn = row_number() over (order by value asc)
      , pct = value/tv.TotalValue
      , target = 1.0 / @groupcount 
  from t
    cross join (select TotalValue = sum(value+.0) from t) tv
)
, remaining as (
select id, value, rn
  , grp = convert(int,((x.sumValueOver/TotalValue)*@groupcount)+1)
from cte
  outer apply (
    select sumValueOver = sum(value) 
    from cte i
    where i.rn <= cte.rn
      ) x
)
select
    grp = row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc)
  , sumValue = sum(value)
from remaining
group by grp
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DEUDJ77007

returns:

```
+-----+----------+
| grp | sumValue |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |     6529 |
|   2 |     4579 |
|   3 |     3483 |
|   4 |     2323 |
|   5 |     1901 |
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Why do you say its flawed?  (apart from getting syntax errors - SQL 2008 R2)

Comment: @Drammy I missed the sql-server 2008-R2 in the description, so I added that tag to your question. You can tinker with it here though: http://rextester.com/UNV61100

Comment: Would like to accept this as the answer given the figures produced but the syntax doesn't work on SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm not 100% why

Comment: @Drammy SQL Server 2008R2 doesn't support `over()` with an `order by` clause.

Comment: @Drammy Updated with a 2008 compatible version

Answer (score 1):

Here [`NTILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) function in sql server may help you.

```
DECLARE @GroupCount INT = 5

-- Set up the test data
DECLARE @test TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Value INT)
INSERT  @Test (Value)
SELECT  100
UNION ALL
SELECT  456
UNION ALL
SELECT  121
UNION ALL
SELECT  402
UNION ALL
SELECT  253
UNION ALL
SELECT  872
UNION ALL
SELECT  765
UNION ALL
SELECT  6529
UNION ALL
SELECT  1029
UNION ALL
SELECT  342
UNION ALL
SELECT  98
UNION ALL
SELECT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT  0
UNION ALL
SELECT  4
UNION ALL
SELECT  46
UNION ALL
SELECT  23
UNION ALL
SELECT  456
UNION ALL
SELECT  416
UNION ALL
SELECT  2323
UNION ALL
SELECT  4579

;With cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, NTILE(@GroupCount) OVER(ORDER BY Value DESC) AS GroupNo FROM @Test
)
SELECT GroupNo, SUM(Value) AS SummedValues FROM cte
GROUP BY GroupNo
```

and i get this result.

```
GroupNo SummedValues
--------------------
1       14460
2       2549
3       1413
4       365
5       28
```

Comment: I think they want the values more close to each other

Comment: This puts ALL the first n largest into the first grouping.  I need the first n largest values into separate groupings and so on, and yes as scsimon says I need the numbers more evenly spread

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way to do this would be to "snake" the selections.  You're lining up the 1st, 6th, 11th highest - of course that's way higher than 5th, 10th, 15th.

Better would be 1st, 10th, 11th, versus 5th, 6th, 15th.  Still not perfect, and with your particular data still *very* poor, but slightly better than yours.

```
DECLARE @GroupCount INT = 5

-- Set up the test data
DECLARE @test TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Value INT)
INSERT  @Test (Value)
SELECT  100
UNION ALL
SELECT  456
UNION ALL
SELECT  121
UNION ALL
SELECT  402
UNION ALL
SELECT  253
UNION ALL
SELECT  872
UNION ALL
SELECT  765
UNION ALL
SELECT  6529
UNION ALL
SELECT  1029
UNION ALL
SELECT  342
UNION ALL
SELECT  98
UNION ALL
SELECT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT  0
UNION ALL
SELECT  4
UNION ALL
SELECT  46
UNION ALL
SELECT  23
UNION ALL
SELECT  456
UNION ALL
SELECT  416
UNION ALL
SELECT  2323
UNION ALL
SELECT  4579


--Order by Value descending
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) RowNum
    FROM    @Test
)
--use modulus to split into grouping
, cte2 AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RowNum % (@GroupCount*2 ) ORDER BY RowNum DESC) Rnk
    FROM    cte
)
select [Grouping], SUM(value) from (
SELECT  floor(abs(@GroupCount - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk ORDER BY Value DESC) - 0.5)) + 0.5) AS 'Grouping'
    ,Value
    ,Id
FROM    cte2
--ORDER BY [Grouping], Value ASC
) a group by [Grouping]
  order by [Grouping] ASC
```

Ultimately though I think random assignment is likely better than this, maybe random assignment while checking that the sum isn't already 2*(1/grouping * total).

Really I think this is not a problem well solved by TSQL or any SQL; languages that can control flow on a row by row basis will better serve you.  Python, C#, SAS, whatever other tool that is in your toolbox.  (PL/SQL is the one place I'd consider going here...)

Anything that would let you say, on a row-level basis, "Having kept track of what I've assigned so far, assign this particular case to the bucket with the lowest number so far" really would work better.

```
Grouping Summed Values
---------------------

1       1781
2       1608
3       2904
4       5249
5       7273
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about a kind of snaking but couldn't get what I wanted.  I was trying to work it so that on each n pass I'm alternating between taking the values in ascending and descending order.  I think that should work best given the restraints you describe in TSQL.  On reflection that is the same effect as what you have done here.

Comment: I know what you're saying about it being the wrong tech for the job; indeed I've already implemented this in C#.  I was just keen to learn the best way to get close to achieving it with TSQL's limitations

Comment: Even in a proper programming language (SAS, in my case, but any of them above) this is quite a hard problem to get optimized.  With a fair amount of room for error you can get a lot better than this, but still difficult to get exactly right.  And in SQL where you have to apply the same thing to the whole set, it's a mess (without having a bunch of case-when stuff that makes it a disaster to read).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ntile` and the `row_number` window functions together to not only split it into the even groups (even by count, not sum) but make a better decision of what values to include in each group to even out the total in each group as much as possible.

**Answer:**

```
select case b.grp_split when 1 then b.grp_split_rnk_desc else grp_split_rnk_asc end as [grouping]
, b.value
, b.id
from (
    select a.id
    , a.value
    , a.grp_split
    , row_number() over (partition by a.grp_split order by a.value desc) grp_split_rnk_desc
    , row_number() over (partition by a.grp_split order by a.value asc) grp_split_rnk_asc
    from (
        select t.id
        , t.value
        , ntile(@ntile_cnt) over (order by t.value desc) as grp_split
        from @test as t
        ) as a
    ) as b
order by case b.grp_split when 1 then b.grp_split_rnk_desc else grp_split_rnk_asc end asc
, b.value asc
```

**Results:**

Not perfect, but slightly closer.

```
Group   Total
1       7029
2       5096
3       2904
4       1761
5       2025
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is primary defined by first largest values. So you can try ordering all the rest in reverse order

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) RowNum
    FROM    @Test
)
--use modulus to split into grouping
, cte2 AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RowNum % @GroupCount ORDER BY RowNum ) Rnk
    FROM    cte
)
,cte3 AS
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk ORDER BY case rnk when 1 then Value else -Value end DESC) AS [Grouping]
    ,Value
    ,Id
FROM    cte2
 )
select [Grouping],sum(value)
from cte3
group by [Grouping]
order by [Grouping];
```

The result

```
  Grouping  (No column name)
1   1   7029
2   2   5096
3   3   2904
4   4   1761
5   5   2025
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean the query is designed by taken the values into consideration.  I think the solution should be independent of the values else we could change the GroupCount and present different values and this approach would no longer be the most accurate.

Comment: I don't think so. If values have rather small variation, any tactic will do. If variation is bigger then most probably the assumption "The result is primary defined by first largest values" is correct.